# How can I get the Region and DNS to appear on my html document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml

I have a YAML script that sets up an Ubuntu server. Under the UserData portion of it, I have an HTML doc that contains information. I want the AWS Region and the Public DNS name of the server to be displayed on the web page once it is created.

I have variables in lines 8, 9 which are supposed to find the EC2 Availability zone and parse through it to find the specific region. Line 11 has the variable for the public DNS. Initially I tried the "sed" command to replace the values (%AWS_REGION% and %DNS_HOSTNAME%) on the HTML page with the variables. When I checked the page after running the script, nothing was replaced. (i.e. "AWS region: %AWS_REGION%" was displayed.)

THEN I tried the code below, I replaced %AWS_REGION% with $EC2_REGION in hopes that the variable would just get substituted in, but when I ran the script, it was blank (i.e. After "AWS region:" there was nothing, where last time %AWS_REGION% was there.)

```
UserData:
    'Fn::Base64': |
      #!/bin/bash -x

      # set timezone
      timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
      # get region
      EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
      EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed 's/[a-z]$//'`"
      # get DNS
      EC2_DNS=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`
      # install and setup apache
      apt-get update
      apt-get install -y nginx
      cd /var/www/html
      echo "<title>Jonah Ryder</title> <h1>Jonah Ryder</h1> <p>AWS region: $EC2_REGION</p> <p>Public hostname: %DNS_HOSTNAME%</p>" > index.html
      sed 's/%AWS_REGION%/EC2_REGION/g' index.html
      sed 's/%DNS_HOSTNAME%/EC2_DNS/g' index.html
      service nginx start
```

I want the HTML page to take the variables and display them. I don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: Have you verified that the content in index.html changes? Where is index.html located? Userdata script in EC2 startup sequence are run by 'root' user. Shouldn't you use full absolute path to index.html?

Comment: @marekful I verify it the contents change by creating a stack on AWS. The Index file attains it's own IP address and is accessible. Index.html is located in a directory on the Ubuntu 18.04 Server on AWS IIRC but I don't think I need the full path according to the sample code I was given which looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `EC2_REGION` environment variable after you have set its value, you need to use `$EC2_REGION`, not `EC2_REGION`. This is how you read env variables in general.

Also, it's worth echoing `$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE` and `$EC2_REGION` to stdout after you set them so that you can debug this later, if needed, using the [EC2 instance console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output) log. For example:

```
  EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
  EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed 's/[a-z]$//'`"
  EC2_DNS=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname`

  echo "AZ: $EC2_AVAIL_ZONE"
  echo "Region: $EC2_REGION"
  echo "DNS: $EC2_DNS"
```